# How to set custom properties for an object via its dbid in Autodesk Forge Viewer?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm trying to set custom properties for objects via their dbids but the [API](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/reference/javascript/propertypanel/) they provide doesn't seem to help to achieve that because it requires object to be selected and it doesn't save the property. I also look at [POST references](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-references-POST/) in Model Derivative API and [PATCH](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/projects-project_id-items-item_id-PATCH/) in Data Management API, but they're used at document level, not model item.

Answer (score 2):

All resources in a model are currently read-only, so you won't find any endpoint that allows you to modify a model or its properties.

A workaround is to use a custom database along with custom endpoints exposed by your own server that would allow you to modify overwritten properties. You can take a look at this [live demo](https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/configurator?id=5904729b0007f5ead5b1196d). The source code is available at [Viewing.Extension.MetaProperties](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs/tree/master/src/client/viewer.components/Viewer.Extensions.Dynamic/Viewing.Extension.MetaProperties).

This article also deals with that topic: 
[Use Forge or Spreadsheet to Create Shared Parameters](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/09/use-forge-or-spreadsheet-to-create-shared-parameters.html)