# How do I display the obtained object properties in the properties sheet?

Tags: autodesk-viewer

I am developing a properties panel in which I have to display the properties of the model.
I got the properties of the model with help [this](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/).
I also created a properties panel using [this](https://repl.it/repls/ReadyGrimTechnician) code.

The first thing I need is to find out how I can display the properties of the treated object that I need in the properties panel.
The second thing I would like to know, this is how I can create such a window, had a fixed height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The first thing I need is to find out how I can display the properties of the treated object that I need in the properties panel.

```
let yourProperties;
viewer.model.getProperties(dbid, properties=> yourProperties = properties);
...
MyAwesomePanel.prototype.setProperties = function (properties, options, container) {
  Autodesk.Viewing.Extensions.ViewerPropertyPanel.prototype.setProperties.call(this, yourProperties, options, container); 
...
```

> The second thing I would like to know, this is how I can create such a window, had a fixed height.

**Already explained in my comment in the code sample with your previous question**

Comment: thank you very much. Your advice and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52844714/modify-properties-of-a-model-autodesk-forge) post very helpful.