# Autodesk Forge - load, modify and view Revit model in Forge

Tags: autodesk-forge

We essentially work with Revit and its API.
We export our Revit models into Forge for our customers to view them. 
But we would like them to be able to do simple modifications (such as textures modification) and later larger modifications (change an object for another). And of course visualize the modified model.
Let's start with the simplest task: modify a texture. Is that possible? I understand from [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50178930/how-to-set-custom-properties-for-an-object-via-its-dbid-in-autodesk-forge-viewer?noredirect=1&lq=1) that I could modify metadata of the model. Does this include textures, and does it mean that the modified texture will appear in the model in Forge?
Thanks by advance
Benoit

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer is Yes. You can use the API to modify the metadata, geometry and texture as you mentioned. You can do most of the job that you did in your Revit desktop plugin which doesn't require UI interaction. Of course, it still has some limitation, please refer [Design Automation for Revit limitation](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/developers_guide/quotas/) for some details.

Back to your question to view the Revit model, that's another topic, after you modified the texture of Revit model, you need to trigger another translation and then view it in browser, there are some issue or limitation of Revit material/texture to be translated/viewed in Forge viewer, [handle revit custom texture](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/show-revit-custom-texture-map-viewer) is some suggestion while viewing custom texture.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. A few related questions : 1) do you have a downloadable document explaining how the API works ? We only found online documents and we want to be able to look at it offline. 2) Do you know if the design options are available in Forge? That 's the way we would like to deal with furniture replacement. Thanks

Comment: Q1, I don't think any offline doc, all our doc should be online now. Q2, what do you mean by design options are available in Forge? It's not available in Forge viewer, but should be Ok in Forge Design Automation for Revit plugin.